# Branch/Tag using SharpSvn C#

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I have been trying to Tag a particular folder (on my PC) to an SVN location using `SvnClient`.

I came to know that Branch / Tag is simply a copy operation in Subversion.

1. Is it true that copy to a location is like (or the same as) creating Tag?
2. The `SvnClient.Copy` command has the following signature:

   public bool Copy(SvnTarget sourceTarget, string toPath)

I am using it as:

```
    string CILocalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(NewLabelFolderPath, "CI"); // C:\MyFolder
    string CITagPath = textBoxCI.Text.Replace(textBoxBranchKeyword.Text,textBoxTagKeywork.Text); svn://10.205.10.72/OurFolders

    SvnTarget CITarget = SvnTarget.FromString(CITagPath);
    client.Copy(?,?);
```

Its very confusing and I dont know first parameter is my local path or remote path.

Am I using it correctly?
Please assist me.

**EDIT :**
I placed `C:\MyFolder` as first argument and the other as second and it gave me the following error:

> This argument is not a valid path. A Uri was specified
>   Parameter name: toPath

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would expect the first parameter to be `CITarget` (ie a reference to the source that includes full repository information). I'd then expect the second parameter to be a path in that repository (eg something like `foo/tags/version1.2.3.4/`) but I'm not sure. I'd certainly never expect your local folders to be referenced since a branch/tag is something that happens in the repository, not on your filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy *to* a url you should client.RemoteCopy(, )

SharpSvn uses a different function for this to avoid requiring authorization setup etc, for copying just local directories.